# Which profile should be used for Java Security in SonarQube?

Tags: java, security, sonarqube-4.5

I want to apply security rules in a Java context. If I do a search on the rules in SONARQube 4.5.5, using the tags "security", "owasp", "cert" and "cwe" I find over 150 rules. However, these rules come from several repositories and so I find myself having to build a quality profile to group them.

I see on the SONARQube website that SONARQube is supposed to now have a base of Java security rules from 4.5.4 (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Plugin). Reading the article it seems as though the intention is to allow the application of these security rules more or less automatically.

Can someone please explain how to do so, or perhaps if I have misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

I am a full-stack security engineer and I use Sonarqube at work.  I feel that its better to keep all the Tags so it spans coding conventions, bug detection, and security problems. But at minimum, you should focus on CERT as it is based on CERT's Secure Coding Standards in Java.

See more here:
https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/SEI+CERT+Coding+Standards